# Python importing ActiveX DLL issue

Tags: python, import, dll, activexobject

This will be my first question.

I am trying to use python to import a SDK which provides ActiveX DLL and ocx file.

I tried using

```
    clr.FindAssembly(“dllname.dll”)
    clr.AddReference(“dllname”)
```

to load while I have error showing:

```
    System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find assembly 'MyDLL'
    Python.Runtime.CLRModule.AddReference(String name)
```

Then I tried using

```
    ctypes.WinDLL(‘dllname.DLL’)
```

But I cannot find any functions inside of it.
Can anyone tried to provide any ideas?

Many thanks!